# UIViewRepresentable not updating binding to ObservedObject property?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable, swiftui-14.2-defect

This view is a UIKit slider adapted to my SwiftUI project because in SwiftUI `Slider` cannot change its track color, which is probably a bug since you should be able to change it with `.accentColor`.

Anyway, this slider changes its track color according to its value, from green to red. The whole thing works perfectly (although my gradients aren't that good yet) if `value` is bound to a normal `@State` property, but the second you try to attach it to a property of an `@ObservedObject` it breaks and, although the track color still works, it never changes the underlying value. I would like to think that this is just a bug right now but it's more likely there's something here that needs to be fixed.

```
struct RedscaleSlider: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var value: Double
    
    var min: Double
    var max: Double
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        @Binding var value: Double
        var min: Double
        var max: Double
        
        init(value: Binding<Double>, min: Double = 0, max: Double = 100) {
           _value = value
            self.min = min
            self.max = max
        }
        
        @objc func valueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
            self.value = Double(sender.value)
            sender.minimumTrackTintColor = green_to_red_gradient(value: (Double(sender.value) - min) / (max - min)).into_UIKit_color()
        }
    }
    
    var thumb_color: UIColor = .white
    var track_color: UIColor = .systemBlue
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISlider {
        let slider = UISlider(frame: .zero)
        
        slider.addTarget(
            context.coordinator,
            action: #selector(Coordinator.valueChanged),
            for: .valueChanged
        )
        
        slider.thumbTintColor = thumb_color
        slider.minimumTrackTintColor = track_color
        slider.minimumValue = Float(min)
        slider.maximumValue = Float(max)
        slider.value = Float(value)
        
        return slider
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ UI_View: UISlider, context: Context) {
        UI_View.value = Float(self.value)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> RedscaleSlider.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(value: $value, min: self.min, max: self.max)
    }
}
```

EDIT: Example of how it should be able to be used:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var danger_level: Double
}
struct ExampleView: View {
    @ObservedObject var view_model = ViewModel(danger_level: 50)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(view_model.danger_level.description)
            RedscaleSlider(value: $view_model.danger_level)
            // should update view model just like a Stepper would
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Slider accent color can be changed with `.accentColor()`

Comment: @davidev I just tried it today in the latest version of Xcode on simulator and my iPad. It has no effect.

Comment: Works fine for both with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1, so probably a bug in your environment. Which one do you use?

Comment: @Asperi I'm on Xcode 12.2 (12B45b) and iOS 14.2

Answer (score 2):

`@Binding` is only supposed to be used in a `View`/`UIViewRepresentable`

Instead of having an `@Binding` in the `Coordinator` switch the `init` to receive the `init(_ parent: RedscaleSlider)` then use `parent.value = Double(sender.value)`

```
import SwiftUI

class RedscaleSliderViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var value : Double = 5
    @Published var danger_level: Double = 7.5

}
struct ParentRedscaleSlider: View{
    //@State var value: Double = 5
    @StateObject var vm = RedscaleSliderViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(vm.danger_level.description)
            RedscaleSlider(value: $vm.danger_level, min: 0, max: 10)
            
        }
    }
}
struct RedscaleSlider: UIViewRepresentable {
    //@EnvironmentObject var vm: RedscaleSliderViewModel
    @Binding var value: Double
    
    var min: Double
    var max: Double
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var parent: RedscaleSlider
        
        init(_ parent: RedscaleSlider) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        @objc func valueChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
            let senderVal = Double(sender.value)
            self.parent.value = senderVal
            
            //Missing code
            //sender.minimumTrackTintColor = green_to_red_gradient(value: (Double(sender.value) - min) / (max - min)).into_UIKit_color()
        }
    }
    
    var thumb_color: UIColor = .white
    var track_color: UIColor = .systemBlue
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UISlider {
        let slider = UISlider(frame: .zero)
        
        slider.addTarget(
            context.coordinator,
            action: #selector(Coordinator.valueChanged),
            for: .valueChanged
        )
        
        slider.thumbTintColor = thumb_color
        slider.minimumTrackTintColor = track_color
        slider.minimumValue = Float(min)
        slider.maximumValue = Float(max)
        slider.value = Float(value)
        
        return slider
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ UI_View: UISlider, context: Context) {
        UI_View.value = Float(self.value)
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> RedscaleSlider.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
}

struct RedScaleSlider_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ParentRedscaleSlider()
    }
}
```

Comment: Well one of the main points of this is to be able to use RedscaleSlider in multiple places, like a TextField view, to control lots of different values. This solution is inelegant at best for that. Is there any other way?

Comment: I don’t understand what you are trying to say with inelegant? How were you trying to setup the ObservedObject before? Are you trying ro use it as a a selector? What is your use case? Maybe a complete minimal example would get you a better answer.

Comment: Updated my question with an example

Comment: Then uncomment the `@Binding` and remove the `@EnvironmentObject`in the `UIViewRepresentable`. `@State` and `@ObservableObject` are used for storage (sources of truth). `@Binding` and `@EnvironmentObject` are two-way connectors. (I updated the code). Also, notice how inheriting the `parent` can also remove the initialization of `min` and `max` in the `Coordinator` cleaner code just invoke `parent.min` or `parent.max`

Comment: Of course I jumped on stack overflow and see someone storing the View in a Coordinator... do not do that ever

Comment: @TheCodingArt here is the most prominent example maybe you should talk to Apple about it https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit

Answer (score 0):

`accentColor` is working fine for me like that..

Also your code works fine with a ObservableObject. Here is the demo code:

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var double : Double = 0.0
}
struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var value: Double = 0
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body : some View {
        Slider(value: $value, in: -100...100, step: 0.1)
            .accentColor(.red) //<< here accent color
        
        RedscaleSlider(value: $viewModel.double, min: 5.0, max: 250.0)
        Text(String(viewModel.double))
    }
    
}
```

Comment: MacOS 11 and latest versions of everything? If not must be a bug

Comment: It does not seem to work with a `@StateObject`.